# Ubuntu from flash drive

Tags: usb-drive

I am windows user and using windows 7 on my laptop.
Is there any way i can run practically run and use ubuntu from flash drive or it is necessary to install it on my hard drive.

Please suggest...

Comment: Keep in mind that the lifetime of your USB stick will be shorter. A USB stick is not a hard drive. But if you install Ubuntu in a USB stick you will not feel any difference!

Answer (score 3):

There are instructions for creating a USB stick install of Ubuntu from Windows here: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Answer (score 3):

You are welcome to use **USB stick** for Ubuntu boot.

Just jump here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Choose the **latest stable or the LTS**, then the **architecture**, then download.

Follow the guide written here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

[image: usb installer]

You are done!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a liveCD you can run it and form it you can make it to usb faster without install any extra thing on your windows.

from ubuntu liveCD go to:
`System> Administration> startup disk creator`.

be careful to do not format your hard drive by mistake ;)

Comment: *I am windows user and using windows 7 on my laptop.* - read it careful!

Comment: I know he is a windows user but what i said if he already have a liveCD he can boot from it and make copy of the liveCD to usb.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [Portable installed system that boots in UEFI as well as BIOS mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

It installs Ubuntu on a flash drive , not as a `liveUSB`.

EDIT: if you plan on still being able to use some of the flash drive for storage, then format the first partition  as FAT  because the FAT partition on a flash drive is the only one recognized by Windows as far as I know.